# worksheet.format("A2:A", { "numberFormat": { "type": "DATE_TIME" }}) doesn't work for text

Tags: gspread

I'm trying to log temperature and humidity to a google spreadsheet using gspread and python.
That works, however when I insert a row using the following code:

`worksheet.append_row((datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), temp, humidity))`

now for example cell 'A2' has the value: '12-05-2020 00:11:50 (Note the single quotation mark)
I want the data to be represented in a chart. This cannot be done with the above value so I have to convert it to a date_time value.

`worksheet.format("A2:A", { "numberFormat": { "type": "DATE_TIME" }})`

I expect the entire column to be converted to Date Time. This doesn't convert the values with a single quotation mark.

I spend the whole day trying to get this to work but for some reason I can't seem to find a way to have a 'normal' date_time value added that Google Sheets recognizes as a date_time...

If I enter a (numeric) value manually in a cell in column A. The code to set the format works just fine.
Also if I manually select the column and select he formatting from the menu it works fine with the gspread added date time rows.

I really want it to be done programmatically and not by hand of course. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case, please use `value_input_option` as follows. By this, the date is put as the date object.

#### From:

```
worksheet.append_row((datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), temp, humidity))
```

#### To:

```
worksheet.append_row((datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"), temp, humidity), value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

#### Reference:

- [append_rows(values, value_input_option='RAW', insert_data_option=None, table_range=None)](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=append_row#gspread.models.Worksheet.append_rows)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)